# Is there a way to export multiple layer combinations in Inkscape using the command line?

Tags: inkscape, svg, export

I have an SVG with multiple layers and I need to generate different png/jpeg files containting all possible combinations of certain layers. Is there a way to do this? I thought it might be possible to do this using the shell command line (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04), by creating a code that first opens the SVG file, shows/hides certain layers and then exports it to png/jpeg, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: You could use Inkscape to open an SVG, and hide specific layers/objects, and export as PNG.  Inkscape is free, Open Source, and works on Linux, Windows, and Mac.

Comment: I don't know how layers are organized in the SVG file, but since it is an XML-format, this should be possible, maybe pretty easy. You should create a few simple test files with enough content, to make it obvious, whether your combinations work or not and either work on the files with something like **xmlstarlet** or maybe even with a tool like **sed**. The latter isn*t specialized on XML at all, but is more general about text patterns and can delete blocks of code, here for instance layers. But I don't have the time to try it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you can achieve this via the command line with the use of Inkscape's actions and verbs. The official documentation on this is a little sparse but I found this page which has more info https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_use_Inkscape_in_commandline_mode. If you click on the verb list you can see there's a DeleteLayer verb. You would need to use a scripting language like bash or python to collect a layer list and iterate through the possibilities.